# AWS Lambda - Cognito Identity ID changes with same login

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm using AWS Lambda, Cognito, and API Gateway (orchestrated with [Serverless](https://serverless.com/)) to build an API for my web-app.

A user authenticates using Cognito, and then makes an authenticated request to the API (pattern copied from the [Serverless Stack](http://serverless-stack.com/) tutorial, where I grab their Cognito ID:

`event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId`

Then I grab the user record associated with that `cognitoIdentityId` to perform role/permissions based logic and return the relevant data.

The trouble I've been running into is that when different people (other devs I'm working with, currently) log in using the same credentials, but from different computers (and, in some cases, countries), the `cognitoIdentityId` sent with their request is completely different -- **for the same user `userPool` user record!**

> Note: I am **not** integrating with any "Federated Identities" (ie, Facebook, etc). This is plain old email sign-in. And everyone is using the same creds, but some people's requests come from different Cognito IDs.

This is highly problematic, because I don't see another way to uniquely identify the user record in my DB associated with the Cognito record.

> **QUESTIONS:** Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this? Is this the expected behavior?

---

The API is currently *not* actually plugged into a DB. Because our data structure is still in flux, and the app is far from live, I've built out an API that *acts* like it integrates with a database, and returns data, but that data is just stored in a JSON file. I'll reproduce some of the relevant code below, in case it's relevant.

An example lambda, for fetching the current user:

```
export function getSelf(event, context, callback) {
  const { cognitoID } = parser(event);

  const requester = cognitoID && users.find(u => u.cognitoID === cognitoID);

  try {
    if (requester) {
      return callback(null, success(prep(requester, 0)));
    } else {
      return authError(callback, `No user found with ID: ${cognitoID}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return uncaughtError(callback, error);
  }
}
```

> That parser stuff up top is just a util to get the ID I want.

The associated user record might look like this:

```
  {
    cognitoID: 'us-west-2:605249a8-8fc1-40ed-bf89-23bc74ecc232',
    id: 'some-slug',
    email: 'email@whatever.com',
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt',
    headshot: 'http://fillmurray.com/g/300/300',
    role: 'admin'
  },
```

Comment: Can you PM me your identity pool Id, user pool id, username and some identity Ids received by the other devs?

Comment: @RachitDhall -- PMing doesn't appear to be a feature on SO! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user -- and I don't see contact info on your profile. If you email me at sasha at redshiftdigital dot com, I can respond with the info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cognito User Pools is used to authenticate users and provides you JWT tokens. When you want to access any AWS Services you need AWS Credentials (access key and secret key). This is where you should use Federated Identities. The tokens you get from Cognito User Pools should be exchanged with Federated Identities to get AWS credentials to access other AWS services. The serverless-stack also covers this in [detail](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/cognito-user-pool-vs-identity-pool.html).

Now since you have not added the user pool as an authentication provider in your identity pool, my observation is that you are getting an unauthenticated identity from Federated Identities (you can confirm this from the Amazon Cognito console) which is why it is different for each of your team members. You should add the user pool as an authentication provider in the identity pool and follow the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) to provide the information required in logins map.